# Forcing this process to run on Windows Server 2016

Tags: rdp, windows-server-2016

I'm running an Access Database and have a button that will save the current report as a PDF back to the users computer.  For just a brief moment the below screen is shown. Does anyone know if this process can be manually ran via a command.  The reason for this request is some users get kicked off when this runs while others don't.  Then if they log right back on and run the same report and press the same button the report is saved without kicking them off.

[image: RDP_Connecting_MappedDrive]

Comment: I have tried to check for the path, but each of those test (powershell or via VBA) didn't work, user A would get kicked out, user B would not.  I was hoping to trap for any errors (if possible) when the program from the screenshot runs.